# Distribute load | Traefik and statefulset

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I have deployed a traefik ingress and an statefulset with 2 containers. Due to a point load pod number 1 is at 90% of cpu but still receiving traffic, there is some way that pod number 1 stops receiving traffic due to cpu load and route all requests to pod number 2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the traffic in relation to the resource usage there isn't a straightforward solution.

What you can do and is more appropriate for most usecases, since you don't overload also the other pods in the cluster, is to configure your application to have a load balancer and then scale out/in the pods compared to the amount of used request:

- To configure a load balancer you can use a Ingress or a IngressRoute, depending on the version of Traefik, that routes the traffic to a ClusterIp Service exposing the cluster of statefulset pods.
- On Traefik you can configure some load balancing parameters (https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/), such as *strategy*, *weight*.
- Then, on top of this architectrue, you can configure the K8s HorizontalPodAutoscaler to automatically scale the number of pods.